# ionic3 - ion-select triggered when click on outside ion-select div tag

Tags: html, ionic-framework, drop-down-menu, ionic3

We have a search bar and drop down box in the page. When we click on search bar, the drop down getting invoked. Anybody knows how to stop this.

```
<div>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="setFilteredData()"></ion-searchbar>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCityTag" placeholder="Filter" multiple="true" (ionChange)="onSelectChange()">
      <ion-option selected *ngFor="let city of cityList">{{city}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </div>
```

when we click on search text box, the drop down getting invoked. Don't know how to fix.

Thanks
AK

Answer (score 0):

Although, it is not mentioned in documentation but it is required to put `ion-select` inside `ion-item`, so doing same will solve your problem.

Wrap your `ion-select` with `ion-item` instead of `div`.

Also, please note that putting `selected` attribute for dynamically generated `ion-option` will select all the options for `ion-select`. You may want to put some condition, there.

```
<div>
  <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="setFilteredData()"></ion-searchbar>
</div>
<br/>
<ion-item>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCityTag" placeholder="Filter" multiple="true" (ionChange)="onSelectChange()">
    <ion-option selected *ngFor="let city of cityList">{{city}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html generated by the ion-select results in a child of type button.

I set width & height equal to 0, like

```
.item-cover {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```